# How to create and write excel file using business object?

Tags: vba

I try to create and write excel file where I can put all my  data:
I use this code:

```
 Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path.XLS

            xlApp.Visible = True
```

But It doesn't work!

Comment: create a new Excel file (aka `Workbook`) and then save it ? **OR** just save the `ActiveWorkbook` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado, I have a table business object, I want to split it via a filter, this filter represents my loop, after every iteration, I want to save my results in an excell file.